# Type of Contract/Agreement Forms for Preliminary Illustration/Design sketches

Tags: illustration, contract

I've done about 6-8 hrs of sketches and colored illustrations for a client and believe it was time to introduce a contract before continuing any further illustration work. It's generally an uncomfortable thing to do (especially it's for a close friend) but we're both working on a professional project and deem appropriate to do.

What form would you recommend using to submit with preliminary sketches? Are there any free ones online? I not interested in a formal/full design contract - which I have already - but a short intro one.

Comment: Why would you *not* want a full contract? *Especially* when working with a friend? What's in your regular contract that you would impose on a client but not a friend?

Comment: I'd submit a full form eventually. I just hear that some designers submit a preliminary form before a full version form.

Comment: I've never heard of that, but I suppose you could if you wanted to. What would be the purpose? To outline the broad strokes of the real contract?

Comment: Some clients want to see a general outline of a contract - it doesn't overwhelm them with the a scary, long form! Sometimes they don't have time to read it until they like what they see. I've read that clients like to see that first before tackling the full agreement contract. I was looking to see if any designers have a short version they share online.

Comment: The contract should be the FIRST thing introduced...not after you've already done work.

Comment: Also, FWIW, a formal contract doesn't have to be long (I'd argue that it shouldn't be).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll just have to revise my contract so it's not too long and wordy. I'll probably share my revise version with my lawyer to get feedback as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find many examples of simplified contracts for designers on [docracy.com](http://docracy.com). I'm personally a big fan of the [Contract Killer](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/contract-killer/), which you can amend for your purposes. I generally refuse to do any work before there is an agreement and commitment in place. I advise checking out [no!spec](http://www.nospec.com/faq) to learn more about why not doing spec work is a preferable practice.